# php mailer script error 5

Tags: php, email

### This is my code and i have done everything to make it work but i am stuck. I can't get this code to sent email out ..

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$to  =  "usman_86@rocketmail.com";
$subject = "Find Dealer @ flowsleeve";
$headers = "From: Find Dealer ";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags("usman_86@rocketmail.com") . "\r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$messsage = "
 Name             : ".$_REQUEST['first_name']."
Email            : ".$_REQUEST['email']."
Event Type       : ".$_REQUEST['event_type']."
Event location   : ".$_REQUEST['event_location']."
Last Name        : ".$_REQUEST['last_name']."
Home Phone       : ".$_REQUEST['home_phone']."
Event Date       : ".$_REQUEST['event_date']."
Referrer         : ".$_REQUEST['referrer']."
Message          : ".$_REQUEST['message']."";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: what do you mean by it 'doesn't work'?

Comment: What's the `error 5` bit from?

Comment: Try echoing the last function to check whether it returns true or false. Besides this, add `.` in line 8

Comment: @cylua2 i put this code on a server and when i submit nothing happen ....

Comment: @jon Stirling i have no idea what that mean i am using this site for the first time ...

Comment: Show us the HTML for or whatever file your are handling the action.

Comment: @usman The title of your question says "error 5"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in header section. You forgot to add `.` in line 8. Take a look at this and correct it.

```
      $headers = "From: Find Dealer ";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags("usman_86@rocketmail.com") . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Because of this mistake, header will contain only mime version info, content type and charset.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, without the `if ( isset ..` statement. 
Your code works successfully. Please add additional code or errors.

Make sure you also check your spamfolder.